# Use different background colours in vba userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a `Userform1` consisting of two `ComboBoxes`:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A1:A5").Value
ComboBox2.List = Sheet1.Range("B1:B5").Value
End Sub
```

`ComboBox1` is placed on the `left side` of the `UserForm1`. 
`ComboBox2` is placed on the `rigth side` of the `UserForm1`.

Now I want to seperate the "area" of each `ComboBox` by using a different background colour. 
Therefore, I inserted `Label1` and changed the `BackColor` to blue (`&H00FF0000&`) and `Label2` and changed the `BackColor` to red `(&H000000FF&`).

All this works fine so far.

---

However, now my issue is that I cannot put the `Labels` in the background so the `ComboBox1` and `ComboBox2` are currently hidden by the `Label1` and `Label2`.

Is there a way how I can put them in the background or any other solution how I can use two different background colours on the `UserForm1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the label and select "send backward" (may need to do this more than once), or on the combobox and select "bring forward"